# Use code from executable API in dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, libwebsockets

I'm using **libwebsockets** and **lwsws** to run an **HTTP server** and a **Web Socket server**, but it requires to write the web socket protocol code in a specific **.dll plugin** (HTTP provided by lib). Everything is developped with VS2015 (or VS2008).

The code to initialize and run this server is wrapped in a C++ object that I use in my executable project and this leads me to this problem:

I want to be able to call functions, and use variables, from **the executable project API** in my **.dll plugin** without ending-up with the code being compiled and put in that **.dll**; how can I do that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this works in pretty much the same way that you'd do it the other way around: you have to export the functions from the executable and import them into the DLL.  For example, you could use `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)`, or a definitions file.  Exporting from an application to a DLL is a little unusual, but I gather it works perfectly well.

Comment: Exporting symbols from executable and import them in the dll sounds logic, but how can I deal with the code I don't want to be put in **.dll** after compilation? The other point is, when creating my VS2015 project, I think I would have to include header files, but I'm afraid that I would have to include c code files too, and this will compile and put extra code in my dll, which is not what I want... I'm I right? Are header files enough when compiling the plugin dll only?

Comment: It's the same as linking to a DLL.  Typically, you just include the headers.

Comment: That is great news, because I was really doubting about this and documentation is quiet hard to find in that kind of tricky case. I'll try this and I will come back to you if I succeed. Thanks!